# Logic Question : $C \rightarrow(B\wedge A) = F , A\longleftrightarrow(B\wedge C) = T$ Find $B\rightarrow (\neg C) $

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I have  the following statements:
$$C \rightarrow(B\wedge A) = F , A\longleftrightarrow(B\wedge C) = T$$
I want to find the value of :
 $$B\rightarrow (\neg C) $$

1) I need to do truth table?

2) there is another way to do it?

I can see that from  $C \rightarrow(B\wedge A) = F$ , $C=1 ,(B\wedge A)=0$ its mean that there is 3 options for  $(B\wedge A)=0$ right? now how I can continue from here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do get 3 choices for the values of $A$ and $B$. For each case, check the value of your other condition, $A\leftrightarrow (B\land C)$. Perhaps you can eliminate some of your three possibilities. Once you do that, see what possible values $B\rightarrow(\neg C)$ will take.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are formulas and you know $X \leftrightarrow Y$, you can replace $X$ by $Y$ (or vice versa) in any formula, and the validity of the formula will not change.

Comment: I dont understand what you did, what is the mean of substitue in the first?

Comment: "The second statement says $A=B\land C$". No, it doesn't. Identity is one thing, truth-functional equivalence another.

Comment: I see. I will remove this answer then.

Comment: "If X and Y are formulas and you know X↔Y, you can replace X by Y (or vice versa) in any formula, and the validity of the formula will not change." Again false. If the truth of X↔Y is merely contingent, you can't substitute X for Y and be guaranteed to preserve necessary truth (and hence preserve validity).

Comment: @PeterSmith I believe I may be learning something here. Let me tell you what I understand and please help me spot the wrong part. I understand $X \leftrightarrow Y = T$ as $X \leftrightarrow Y$ being true in all valuations. "I believe" that implies that in any given valuation, the values of $X$ and $Y$ will be the same. Because of this, I cannot find an example of a formula and a valuation that evaluate to different values with $X$ replaced by $Y$. Right now I can only see infinitary logic as the exception of what I said, but I believe I am wrong again?

Comment: @PeterSmith In a sense, I don't feel that the sentence $X \leftrightarrow Y$ is contingent if you are given that $X \leftrightarrow Y = T$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You have correctly observed that $C$ is true and $(B \land A)$ is false. The former allows you to simplify $(B \land C)$ into $B$, combine the result with the latter (there are now only two possibilities) and from there infer the remaining details.

I hope this helps ;-)